# Including vars from several files with same template

Tags: templates, variables, ansible

I want to generate /etc/sudoers.d/ files from the same template, in an Ansible role, but in files located in another path (independent from the role, because of Git repository --> I want roles to be independent).
I have already one template for /etc/sudoers (main file), that works and I want :
- to complete this role with some additional variables, in /etc/sudoers.d/ folder, in separated file
- to be able also to call this role in the future for adding files in /etc/sudoers.d/, with the same template.

I first put all variables in the same file, but obviously, I generated 3 times the same file, with all variables inside :/

### In tasks :

```
name: "Creating Sub sudoers files in {{ sudo_sudoers_d_path }}"
template:
  src: "idc_sudo.d.j2"
  dest: "{{ sudo_sudoers_d_path }}/{{ item.filename }}"
  validate: "visudo -cf %s"
  owner: "{{ sudo_sudoers_user }}"
  group: "{{ sudo_sudoers_group }}"
  mode: "{{ sudo_sudoers_mode }}"
with_items: "{{ sudo_sub_files }}"
when: create_sudoers_subdir == true
```

### In variables with example of Zabbix :

```
filename: "idc_zabbix"
users:
  - name: "zabbix"
    nopasswd: yes
    commands:
    - /usr/bin/cksum /etc/sudoers
```

What I would love to see would be something like : 
- X number of variable files, with dedicated portions of sudo privileges
- On external roles (Zabbix for example), those variables set as vars

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider just changing your with_items loop a little bit:

```
name: "Creating Sub sudoers files in {{ sudo_sudoers_d_path }}"
template:
  src: "idc_sudo.d.j2"
  dest: "{{ item.file_path }}/{{ item.file_name }}"
  validate: "visudo -cf %s"
  owner: "{{ item.user_name}}"
  group: "{{ item.group }}"
  mode: "{{ item.mode }}"
with_items: 
    - { file_name: 'idc_zabbix', file_path: '/etc/sudoers', user_name: "zabbix", group: "some_group", mode: "0744" }
    - { file_name: 'idc_zabbix', file_path: '/etc/sudoers.d', user_name: "zabbix", group: "some_group", mode: "0744" }
when: create_sudoers_subdir == true
```

And you can use these item.whatever variables inside the template as well if you want.  If thats not working because you HAVE to keep these variables somewhere else, or you have so many they are just really ugly to put here, then you could also use a with_dict loop instead:

```
- name: Print phone records
  debug:
    msg: "User {{ item.key }} is {{ item.value.name }} ({{ item.value.telephone }})"
  with_dict: "{{ users }}"
```

Then you can call any list with the correct labels from any place you can import variables (group_vars, host_vars, the var module in a playbook, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much, it helped me to understand better what I wanted !

This is finally what I did :

```
- name: "Creating Main sudoers file {{ main_sudoers_file }}"
  template:
    src: "idc_sudo.d.j2"
    dest: "{{ main_sudoers_file }}"
    validate: "visudo -cf %s"
    owner: "{{ sudo_sudoers_user }}"
    group: "{{ sudo_sudoers_group }}"
    mode: "{{ sudo_sudoers_mode }}"
  with_items: "{{ sudo_files }}"
  tags:
    ["sudo", "config", "config.files"]  

- name: "Creating Global Sub sudoers files in {{ sudo_sudoers_d_path }}/"
  template:
    src: "idc_sudo.d.j2"
    dest: "{{ sudo_sudoers_d_path }}/{{ item.filename }}"
    validate: "visudo -cf %s"
    owner: "{{ sudo_sudoers_user }}"
    group: "{{ sudo_sudoers_group }}"
    mode: "{{ sudo_sudoers_mode }}"
  with_items: "{{ privileges }}"
  when: create_sudoers_subdir == true and privileges is defined
  tags:
    ["sudo", "config", "config.files", "sudoers.d"]

- name: "Creating Additional Sub sudoers files in {{ sudo_sudoers_d_path }}/"
  template:
    src: "idc_sudo.d.j2"
    dest: "{{ sudo_sudoers_d_path }}/{{ item.filename }}"
    validate: "visudo -cf %s"
    owner: "{{ sudo_sudoers_user }}"
    group: "{{ sudo_sudoers_group }}"
    mode: "{{ sudo_sudoers_mode }}"
  with_items: "{{ more_privileges }}"
  when: create_sudoers_subdir == true and more_privileges is defined
  tags:
    ["sudo", "config", "config.files", "sudoers.d"]
```

My error was not in tasks, but in Inventory, putting all my files in group_vars/all. So, obviously, last task was not specific, but global...

So, now, main sudoers file + global sub sudoers are in group_vars/all, but additional sub sudoers has been placed in host_vars/my_host.

My goal is achieved, as I use same template for all sudoers file :)